# Add HTML object to an event javascript/meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze

How can I add HTML objects to an event?
I would like to do something like this:

```
Template.Schedule.events({
    'dblclick .mycol' (event){
        event.target.childNodes.append("<strong>Test</strong>");
    }
});
```

I know I could style it and change the innerHTML and so on for the given example, but I actually want to add other HTML objects, like a select-tag, how can I do that?

Comment: Is this the complete code snippet? It looks like you have missed something in first line of code.

Comment: I forgot the Template first line, but this is purely meteor syntax/rules, but I added it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The vanilla JS way

You could use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) here to change the html content of the clicked element:

```
'dblclick .mycol' (event){
  const target = event.currentTarget
  target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML + "<strong>Test</strong>"
}
```

If you want to manipulate the parent in the event you can use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

#### The jQuery way

Your approach of using [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is requiring jQuery:

```
'dblclick .mycol' (event){
  $(event.currentTarget).append($("<strong>Test</strong>"))
}
```

#### Bonus: Optimization for using jQuery

In a meteor blaze template-events each event has a reference to the template instance. This template instance keeps [a reference to a jQuery object](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-%5C$) and it's part of the DOM that it manipulates.

> template.$ returns a jQuery object of those same elements. jQuery
>   objects are similar to arrays, with additional methods defined by the
>   jQuery library.
>
> The template instance serves as the document root for the selector.
>   Only elements inside the template and its sub-templates can match
>   parts of the selector.

You can access it via `templateInstance.$` if your seconds event parameter is namend `templateInstance`. With

```
'dblclick .mycol' (event, templateInstance){
  templateInstance.$(event.currentTarget).append($("<strong>Test</strong>"))
}
```

This saves jQuery the need to traverse the whole DOM, makes it more efficient on large documents.

#### The Meteor Blaze way

Now these are neat little tricks when there is need for manipulation on a small scale. However, you may want your app to be scalable and profit all the time from the Blaze rendering engine.

In such cases you may rather want to generate a way of dynamically inserting templates.

Consider the following template, that is nowhere imported yet:

rowcontent.html

```
<template name="rowcontent">
    <strong>Test</strong>
    <p>someData{{someData}}</p>
</template>
```

rowcontent.js

```
import './rowcontent.html' // currently just the import
```

You can dynamically add it at runtime to an element using [Blaze.renderWithData](http://blazejs.org/api/blaze.html#Blaze-renderWithData) so:

```
'dblclick .mycol' (event, templateInstance) {
    import './rowcontent.js' // use the right path here
    Blaze.renderWithData(Template.rowcontent, {someData: 'toBePassedToRowContent'}, event.currentTarget)
 }
```

which will result in:

---

This is my col **Test**

someDatatoBePassedToRowContent

---

The advantage of this approach is that you can pass the data to the template and have all the reactive benefits remaining, thus handle the newly added template like any other template in Meteor.

#### Alternatives

Declarative dynamic templates using [Template.dynamic](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic)